# JQuery Remove() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, element

I have a DIV element inside another as follows:

```
<div id="filters">
    <div class="filterData">hello</div>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to remove the element:

```
$("#filters").remove('.filterData');
```

Problem is, it doesn't. I've tested on other elements on my page and it works. The thing is, I cannot append to it, show or hide it, use .empty. I've also changed it to be a DIV with 'filterData' as the ID and told JQuery to remove it but it refuses to...

Has anyone had a stuborn element like this before?

EDIT: I'm also trying to remove it inside a `$(document).ready` function so I have no idea.

Answer (score 21):

That is not how [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) works

Use

```
$("#filters .filterData").remove();
```

---

If you use a selector as a parameter to `remove` it acts as a filter on the existing set, not as `find`..

So you could use `$("#filters .filterData").remove(':first');` if you had many `.filerData` and wanted to remove the first.. (*just an example*)

Comment: Not sure this is the case. http://api.jquery.com/remove/ suggests that a selector _can_ be passed to `.remove()`

Comment: @RobCowie Yes, but if you notice it says, ***selector*** expression that **filters** the set of matched elements to be removed. (*update answer to reflect this*)

Comment: Nope, still no luck. The element is still present.

Comment: @XanderGuerin are you adding that element dynamically / with ajax ? Also make sure that there is no other element with id `filters` as it must be unique..

Comment: No, the element is already present on a HTML page. In a JS file, I get the value from it, do some stuff and I'm trying to remove it when done.

Comment: Also to clarify, I have other JQuery methods working in this same file + tried manipulating other elements which work. All done once the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Xander, any errors in the console (maybe the script fails before reaching this line..)? (if you run the command from the console does it still fail ?).. Can you post a live example somewhere ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really post a sample anywhere. How would I post info to a console (I'm using IE9). I have the script debugging in VS Web Developer and I can confirm the line does run and does not throw any error (or at least with VS).

Comment: @XanderGuerin on IE9 press F12 to open the developer tools, and go to console. Refresh to see if errors occur, and you can run the command at the bottom to see if it executes..

Answer (score 3):

Gaby is correct, you need to just use .remove() and not .remove('.filterData'). Or if you still want to keep your div, but just take out everything in there, you can use .empty()

```
$(".filterData").empty();
```